# Keycloack - User not found message information not displayed when reset password

Tags: java, error-handling, freemarker, keycloak

On my keycloak server, when i go to page "reset password" and i enter a bad username, the return message say "You should receive an email shortly with further instructions." But, i want to send a message like "username not found"

On the console log i see the error "user_not_found" and i don't understand why i don't see the same thing on server.

```
WARN [org.keycloak.events] (default task-31) type=RESET_PASSWORD_ERROR, realmId=XXX, clientId=XXX, userId=XXX, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=user_not_found, auth_method=XXX, redirect_uri=http://localhost/, code_id=XX, username=test
```

My keycloak server is on 3.4

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want that?  The default is much more secure - it prevents someone from guessing at existing users on your system.

Comment: Yes, the website is internal and the user need to know if they enter a bad username

Answer (score 0):

Forgot password has default implementation. If you want to change it you have to:
1. create your own provider for "Choose User";
2. create a new FLOW with it.
3. change bidings for Reset Credentials with new FLOW.
More information you can find on:
http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html